# Show that every $x\in [0, 1]$ has the form $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}a_i$, where each $a_i$ is $0$ or $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Show that every $x\in\ [0, 1]$ has the form $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}a_i$, where each $a_i$ is $0$ or $1$.

**Proof**: Clearly $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}a_i \in [0 ,1]$; but how do I choose the $a_i$'s such that the sum is equal to any arbitrary real number on the interval $[0, 1]$?

Any **HINT** would be appreciated-many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you think on what happens to the partial sum $$\sum_{n=k}^m2^{-n}?$$

Comment: Try constructing a sequence by induction and show that the $n$-th partial sum $s_n$ is within $1/2^n$ of $x$.

Comment: You may also check at binary as a number base system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \ge 1/2$, then $a_1 = 1$; otherwise $a_1 = 0$.  Now look at $x - a_1/2$ and apply this procedure recursively.